# Настройка Apache для\с Django

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, apache

колеги. Вошел в заблуждение и не могу понять что к чему.
Ситуация такая: решил я реализовать свой веб проект на python-django.
Для обеспечения хорошей работы работы сайта мне понадобилось взять виртуал. сервер в аренду на котором я установил Ubuntu_18-04. Опыт в развертывании веб серверов есть, но с джангой у меня получились проблемы. Я решил развернуть на Apache, дополнительно нашел себе инструкцию. Так назіваемую "интеграцию" я выполнял по ней https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-setup-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod-wsgi-on-ubuntu
Все выполнил и у меня не работает. Просто в моей ситуации есть разница с ситуацией на этом сайте. Они выводят на локалхост, а мне нужен вывод непосредственно на айпишник сервака(домен потом прикрутим, айпишник белый в сетях пробивается) То-есть после выполнения я так-же само вижу страницу "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" а не страницу джанги. Не могу найти ответа на просторах интернета, по этому прошу помощи у вас. Заранее благодарен.(Если надо конфигы то я предоставлю, просто скажите какие)

Comment: Вместо Apache лучше используйте nginx+gunicorn

Comment: @andreymal nginx-ом не приходилось пользоватся. Его проще будет подружить с джангой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все-ж таки я решил использовать nginx. Спасибо за подсказку. В работе использовал данную инструкцию [How to Deploy Django on Nginx with uWSGI (full tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpR1W-NWnp4)
может кому понадобится

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)